# Find the missing number between [0, n] (n and numbers from 0 to n-1 are given by the user) using DAC

Tags: algorithm

As a homework, I have to find the missing number from 0 to n using a divide and conquer (DAC) algorithm.

As an input, I get n-1 numbers from [0, n] and n.

I can easily do this with a quicksort and then just see which number is missing, but that would mean the complexity of my algorithm will be O(n*log n).

I'm wondering if there is any way I can do lower than that.

I was thinking that I might get the sum of the input (somehow) using DAC, and then the number missing will be n - sum. This would be O(n) complexity.

Is there any other way to get a complexity lower than O(n) (without using any space) and also, is my idea a good one? If not, can you give me other ideas for this problem, please?

Thanks.

Edit:

I know I should post another question, but I can post only once every 90 minutes (as I recall) and I want to finish this problem now if possible.

How can I calculate the sum of an array using DAC?

```
int DAC(int low, int high, int a[], int& s)
{
    if (low <= high)
    {
        int pivot = (low + high)/2;
        s += DAC(low, pivot - 1, a, s);
        s += DAC(pivot+1, high, a, s);
        return a[pivot];
    }
}
```

for this call

```
cout << DAC(0, n-1, a, s);
Input:
7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I get 4 and I don't understand why. I didn't expect it to return only 4.

Edit 2:
I was getting call because I had to cout<<s, not DAC, I'm sorry.
Now I get 52 for the following code, with input: n=7, a=1 2 3 4 5 6 7

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void citire(int& n, int a[])
{
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}

int DAC(int low, int high, int a[], int& s)
{
    if (low <= high)
    {
        int pivot = (low + high)/2;
        s += DAC(low, pivot - 1, a, s);
        s += DAC(pivot+1, high, a, s);
        return a[pivot];
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[100], n, s = 0;
    citire(n, a);
    DAC(0, n-1, a, s);
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be `n(n+1)/2 - sum`;` Besides, complexity is at least O(n) as all n values must be considered

Comment: @Damien yes. You are right with both observations. Thanks for the heads up. So, is my idea okay?

Comment: It looks OK for me. Just pay attention to a possible overflow when calculating the sum

Comment: @Damien can you check my edit, please?

Comment: Are you sure that the input is unsorted? This would be a very typical binary-lookup kind of problem with a sorted input...

Comment: @tucuxi yes. The input is 100% unsorted :)

Comment: If you modify `s`, DAC doesn't need to return something. However, you may add `s += a[pivot]`. Besides, if `DAC`is supposed to return something, it should *always* return something.

Comment: The algorithm you should look at is [quick select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

Comment: Instead of DAC, it should be much simpler to use std::accumulate

Comment: @Damien I'm really sorry, I did something really stupid, that's why I was getting 4. Can you check my second edit?

Comment: @user3386109 I will. thanks :)

Comment: For your DAC to work: `DAC(low, pivot - 1, a, s);\\ DAC(pivot+1, high, a, s);\\ s += a[pivot];` and DAC returns void. But again, std::accumulate is better

Comment: if you want, you can add that as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that the problem should have said a SORTED input.  And now divide-and-conquer makes sense as a strategy.

Comment: @btilly That's true. On the other hand, with an unsorted array, quick select (with O(n) performance) is an improvement over sorting (O(nlogn) performance). But of course, the *"add em all up"* strategy needs to be prohibited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `s`is modified internally, the function `DAC` doesn't have to return anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void citire(int& n, int a[])
{
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
}

void DAC(int low, int high, int a[], int& s)
{
    if (low <= high)
    {
        int pivot = (low + high)/2;
        DAC(low, pivot - 1, a, s);
        DAC(pivot+1, high, a, s);
        s += a[pivot];
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[100], n, s = 0;
    citire(n, a);
    DAC(0, n-1, a, s);
    std::cout << s << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But `std:accumulate`would be much simpler